# Ruby hash returning incorrect values

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have the following function in ruby for retrieving certain information from a database.

```
#Setup

require "mysql2"
@client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "127.0.0.1", :username => "root", :password => "password")
query = "use project1"
@client.query(query)

def nodeslastactive
  query = "SELECT nodeid FROM nodes WHERE lastactive = #{@clock-1}"
  result = @client.query(query)
  if result.size == 0
    return nil
  else
    resultarray = Array.new
    result.each do |row|
      resultarray.push(row["nodeid"])
    end
  end
end
```

It is utilized by this code:

```
lastactivenodes = nodeslastactive
if lastactivenodes != nil
  lastactivenodes.each do |lastactivenode|
    connect(node,lastactivenode)
  end
end
```

The issue I am getting is that when the connection is established in the 2nd code block, the function tries to connect the node with the value `{"nodeid"=>xxxxx}`, even though I have copied all hash values out of the hash into an array in the 1st code block for processing by the second block. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method you miss the

```
return resultarray
```

in the else branch, or it will just return the `result` hash as it is the last thing evaluated in the method

Comment: Cannot believe I missed that.... been up for about 3 hours trying to figure this out... goes to show sometimes a fresh pair of eyes is what you need - Lifesaver... cheers guido